# How to access elements in this data structure?

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

I have a variable called $ip_data and when I do 'print $ip_data;'
it shows something like this: ARRAY(0x3c353cc4);

Data::Dump gives me the following structure:

```
[
 {
   ip => "127.0.0.1",
   list => [
     "France",
     "Safari",
   ],
 },
]
```

I would like to extract `ip` (IP address), `country` and `browser` and put it in a hash that looks like this:

```
%ip_info = (  ip       => '127.0.0.1',
              country  => 'France',
              browser  => 'Safari' );
```

So far all my attempts to dereference it have failed. As I understand it $ip_data is an array that has a hash for an element, and that hash's first element is a string, but the second is an array holding two string elements.

Am I wrong about it? If so please tell me what's going on here and how to get those elements in `%ip_info`.

Comment: Your desired "destination" hash has one key and that key's value is undef. You want (parens) rather than {curlies}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$ip_data` is a reference to array containing a single element (a hash reference). You can construct your hash like this:

```
my %ip_info = (
    ip      => $ip_data->[0]{ip},
    country => $ip_data->[0]{list}[0],
    browser => $ip_data->[0]{list}[1],
);
```

I suggest you to read the [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) manual page to find out more about using references in Perl.

Comment: Thanks eugene y for the fast response. This upcoming weekend will be my "grok the references or die" weekend :)

Comment: perlreftut has an excellent gentle introduction: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html

Answer (score 1):

eugene y's answer gives you your specific use case. To learn more read [`perldoc perlreftut`](http://p3rl.org/reftut) and for the full story [`perldoc perlref`](http://p3rl.org/ref)